# dynamic DropDownList set Selected = true

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOptionDependant" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
  DataSourceID="sdsOptionDependant" DataTextField="product_option_name" 
  DataValueField="product_option_id" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
  <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="None"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

This DropDownList is built from a Query,
I need to dynamically check the product_option_id and when I find a match set that match to the selected= true

Comment: This is server side dropdown how you build it with jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using the DataBound event of the DropDownList. Here is an example.. In your aspx page you need to add the OnDataBound property like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOptionDependant" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
    DataSourceID="sdsOptionDependant" DataTextField="product_option_name" 
    DataValueField="product_option_id" AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
    OnDataBound="ddlOptionDependant_DataBound">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="None"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</asp:Content>
```

And in your code behind add this:

```
protected void ddlOptionDependant_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Get the value of the ID you want to match here:
    int someId = 1;
    foreach(ListItem item in ddlOptionDependant.Items)
            item.Selected = item.Value == someId.ToString();
}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: This is in Visual Basic and the DropDownList is created straight from the Query. <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsOptionDependant" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SqlConnection %>"my Query">
<SelectParameters>
 <asp:SessionParameter Name="option_id" SessionField="EditProduct" Type="Int32" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>